# Show that $\forall x,y\in G$, $(xy)^2=x^2y^2\iff G $ is an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I want to show that $\forall x$,$y\in G$, $(xy)^2=x^2y^2 \iff G $ is an abelian group.

Proof of the backward direction seems easy enough:

Assume $G$ is an abelian group. Then consider $(xy)^2=(xy)(xy)$. By associativity, $(xy)(xy)=xyxy$. Since $G$ is abelian, $xyxy=xxyy=x^2y^2$.

Proof of the forward direction I attempt by contrapositive:

That is, assume $G$ is not an abelian group. Then, consider $(xy)^2=xyxy$ as above. Yet, $xyxy\neq xxyy=x^2y^2$ since we no longer have commutativity.

Is this proof by contrapositive completely correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. The inequality you state may be not true for all $x,y \in G$.

Comment: No. You have to show commutativity like $ab =ba$.

Comment: It's simpler than you are making it.  if $g=h$ then $x^{-1}gy^{-1}=x^{-1}hy^{-1}$.  Now apply this to $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$

Comment: Saying that $G$ is not abelian means that $xy\ne yx$ *for some* $x$ and $y$, not that $xy\ne yx$ *for all* $x$ and $y$. For instance, if $y=1$, then $xy=yx$.

Comment: In other words you are assuming that the centre of the group is trivial.Which may not be the case every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

suppose $xyxy = xxyy$

$x^{-1}(xyxy)y^{-1} = x^{-1}(xxyy)y^{-1}$

$yx = xy$